# TFS build health - Monitoring tool

Tags: tfs, prometheus

I have a requirement which I have to monitor why often build agents take quite a time.

I have Prometheus running on a server and WMI exporter running on private VSTS agent. All I'm able to read is basic metrics like CPU, network etc.

Is it possible to read build metrics or any other way to read health?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to read build metrics or any other way to read health?

We cannot read the build metrics directly, we can track the builds with logs. However you can try below things to monitor TFS:

- Generally if you are a TFS administrator, you could see `Job Summary`, `Job Queue`, `Job history` under the `Job Monitoring` tab by browsing to the following address: 
  http://your-server:8080/tfs/_oi/. You could also see `Activity Log` in
  the page. Refer to below link for details:

  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2013/02/13/tfs2012-new-tools-for-tfs-administrators/
- You could also use the system tool like event viewer or performance
  viewer, for more information, you could refer to the following link:

  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833877(v=vs.90).aspx

In you scenario seems you just want to monitor the TFS Job Agent, and TFS Build Agents, reference below blogs to know more about the TFS Monitoring:

- [Monitoring Team Foundation Server 2018](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/08/monitoring-team-foundation-server-2018/)
- [Monitoring build resources with the TFS 2017 management pack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/03/28/monitoring-build-resources-with-the-tfs-2017-management-pack/)